# LINQ Query - sql equivalent of select * from tablename where columnname =columnvalue

Tags: c#

I am trying to find the LINQ equaivalent of

`select * from usertable where groupof=groupuser`

I have the following code

```
var UserList = await usertableservice.GetUsers() as List<UserTable>;
        var query = from c in UserList
                    where c.GroupOf.Contains(groupuser) 
                    select c;
        return query.FirstOrDefault().UserId;
```

The GetUsers() function will list all the users then I filter if the groupof column contains  a specific string.

But what happens here is
`select * from usertable`  (this may contain 1 million records)
then I am filtering, I guess its totally wrong and resource intensive. What is the best way of doing this?

service layer code:

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<UserTable>> GetUsers()
        {
            try
            {

                var response = await httpClient.GetAsync("api/userinfo");

                if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    if (response.StatusCode == System.Net.HttpStatusCode.NoContent)
                    {
                        return Enumerable.Empty<UserTable>();
                    }
                    string s = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                    //return Enumerable.Empty<LookupTable>();
                    return await response.Content.ReadFromJsonAsync<IEnumerable<UserTable>>();
                }
                else
                {
                    var message = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                    throw new Exception($"Http status code: {response.StatusCode} message: {message}");
                }

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                //Log exception
                throw;
            }
        }
```

controller code

```
 [HttpGet]
        public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<UserTable>>> GetAllUsers()
        {
            try
            {
                var list = await this.userTableRepository.GetUsers();


                if (list == null)
                {
                    return NotFound();
                }
                else
                {
                    //var LookuplistDtos = lookuplist.ConvertToDto();

                    return Ok(list);
                }

            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                return StatusCode(StatusCodes.Status500InternalServerError,
                                "Error retrieving data from the database");

            }
        }
```

Repository code

```
        public async Task<IEnumerable<UserTable>> GetUsers()
        {
            var item = await this.riskDBContext.UserTables
                                               .ToListAsync();
            return item;
        }
```

The flow is
UI -> service layer -> api -> repository

Comment: should post your entity composition to get a complete answer.
Contains is not the same as =

Comment: You need to change your `GetUsers` to not return the whole table but instead return a query (`IQueryable`), which you can then extend with filtering.

Comment: an example ????

Comment: Can you provide your code from method GetUsers

Comment: `var u = UserList.FirstOrDefault(x = x.GroupOf == groupuser); if (u != null) ....`

Answer (score 1):

I agree - it would be wrong to pass million items through api layer for filtering in UI layer.

IQueryable can't be used in UI layer because it can't be serialized - so it cannot be moved through Api layer.

All heavy data filtering should be in repository level but filtering parameter "groupuser" should be passed through flow from UI to repository.

For the sake of brevity and clarity, I did not include error handling here.

UI code:

```
var User = await usertableservice.GetUserByGroup(groupuser);
return User.UserId;
```

Service layer code:

```
public async Task<UserTable> GetUserByGroup(string userGroup)
{
    var response = await httpClient.GetAsync("api/userbygruop?userGroup="+userGroup);
    return await response.Content.ReadFromJsonAsync<UserTable>();
}
```

Api Controller code:

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("userbygruop")]
public async Task<ActionResult<UserTable>> GetUserByGroup(string userGroup)
{
    var user = await this.userTableRepository.GetUserByGroup(userGroup);
    return Ok(user);
}
```

Repository code:

```
public async Task<UserTable> GetUserByGroup(string userGroup)
{
    var UsersQuery = this.riskDBContext.UserTables;
    
    var query = from c in UsersQuery
            where c.GroupOf.Contains(userGroup) 
            select c;
            
    var filteredUser = await query.FirstOrDefaultAsync();

    return filteredUser;
}
```

Comment: i did the same thing, i would be interested to know if we can leverage using IQueryable in this design. If we cannot, then which situations warrant the use of  IQueryable ?

Comment: IQueryable can be leveraged when you have complex filtering where multiple methods are involved and IQueryable is passed as parameter, but actual data querying happens at the end.

Comment: In my example in repository code var "UsersQuery" and "query" both implements IQueryable and they can be passed as parameters for methods to add some additional filters before await query.FirstOrDefaultAsync()

Comment: As I mentioned, IQueryable can't be serialized - so it cannot be moved through Api layer and can't be levereged in this design.